# Xamarin.Android <queries> element but as activity attribute in code instead

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, deep-linking

Android 11 adds the visibility feature that requires a `<queries>` element in the android manifest for an app to be capable of deep linking into another. Is it possible to define that in code using an attribute instead of directly in the manifest?

Example intent filter:

```
[IntentFilter(
  new[] { Intent.ActionView },
  Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
  DataHost = "mydomain.com",
  DataScheme = "http"
)]
```

And then I'd like to add the `<queries>` element here in code as well. The reason is I have multiple manifests, used at different environments but the multiple custom app schemes I will define in the  element will be the same for all environments and they will be more than 5 so I don't want to repeat N times.

In the Manifest, it looks like this:

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="customappscheme" />
        </intent>
</queries>
```

Don't know if it's possible but if it is, in code it will probably look similar to:

```
Queries = new [] { "appscheme1", "appscheme2" }
```

as part of the IntentFilter attribute

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can refer to the following code:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    // The URL should either launch directly in a non-browser app (if it's the
    // default), or in the disambiguation dialog.
    intent.addCategory(CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Only browser apps are available, or a browser is the default.
    // So you can open the URL directly in your app, for example in a
    // Custom Tab.
    openInCustomTabs(url);
}
```

For more, you can refer document: [Fulfilling common use cases while having limited package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases) .

Comment: Actually my problem is different, I just added the AndroidManifest version that I want written in code as a class attribute instead to my question to clarify.

Comment: From the android document [queries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element), `queries` does not have such syntax currently .

Comment: Okay thank you! Then for now I will keep all the values repeated into my 4 manifest files until I can do that only in one.